# Clear and concise instructions for an account creation CAPTCHA with MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki, captcha, accounts

We get our share spam accounts on our MediaWiki, and we'd like to curb it. According to MediaWiki's [Extension:ConfirmAccount](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ConfirmAccount):

> The ConfirmEdit extension can be used (in conjunction with the ConfirmAccount extension) in order to use captchas to stop flood requests...

Then, in MediaWiki's [API:Account creation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Account_creation#CAPTCHA):

> When used with Extension:ConfirmEdit, a CAPTCHA may be presented for new account creations...

The API/CAPTCHA docs then go to provide what looks like a few JSON strings, without information how to actually enable a CAPTCHA at account creation without the need for *Sysops* or *Bureaucrats* intervention.

Can someone provide clear and concise instructions on how to enable enable a CAPTCHA at account creation without the need for *Sysops* or *Bureaucrats* approval under MediaWiki 1.25?

(My apologies for a broad question like this. I prefer to ask narrow questions, but the MediaWiki docs are so crummy in this area I have to beg for the answer).

Comment: Somewhat unsurprisingly, the instructions about enabling the ConfirmEdit extension can be found on the [ConfirmEdit extension documentation page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ConfirmEdit), not in the API docs or the documentation pages of unrelated extensions.

Comment: @Tgr - Its account creation; not editing. That seems very related to me (but I'm not a WikiMedia expert).

Comment: ConfirmEdit shows captchas in various places (including registration); ConfirmAccount is about sysops confirming accounts (ie. replacing open registration with registration requests which have to be confirmed). //The ConfirmEdit extension can be used (in conjunction with the ConfirmAccount extension) in order to use captchas to stop flood requests...// means that when you are using ConfirmAccount, you can use the captchas provided by ConfirmEdit to prevent being flooded by registration requests by spammers.

Answer (score 1):

If you enable ConfirmAccount, you don't need CAPTCHAs for account creation any longer. Just drop ConfirmEdit, if your wiki becomes closed access.